# Problems with the solver configuration for two planning entity classes

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on a solution of a problem that is close to the Nurse Rostering Example in optaplanner .

Employees are assigned to shifts as in the Nurse Roster but the main difference is that there are also skill requirements (assignments) that last lets say 20 minutes. An employee can be assigned to a skill requirement if he gets assigned to a shift that covers the given skill requirement time. Lets say we have a skill requirement for Skill1 from 12:00 to 12:20 and an employee is assigned on a shift from 08:00 to 16:00 then he can be assigned to that skill requirement only if he has that skill.

I have 2 planning entity classes. The default shift assignment in the example, and i have implemented 2 more classes SkillRequirement class which will hold one skill requirement in the given time frame (this will be a planning fact) , and the second planning entity class will be between the Employee and the SkillRequirement class and the name of it will be EmployeeSkillRequirement.

By now i think i have done everything good i annotated the EmployeeSkillRequirement
 class as @PlanningEntity and the planning variable with the appropriate value range, in the planning solution i added the lists for the skill requirements(which are facts and also go into drools working memory) and the list of employees on skill requirements which are the planning entities and are properly annotated with @PlanningEntitySolutionProperty

I'm having a hard time configuring the solver, i have tried many different solver configurations, i read in the documentation that when there are more planning entities and/or planning variables a union of move selectors should be used where you tell OptaPlanner the name of the planning entity class and planning variable, because it cant find it by default.

None seem to work and i get this exception all the time

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalling of solverConfigResource (org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringSolverConfig.xml) fails.
```

Here are the configurations i' have been trying to use:

**Config 1:**

In this configuration the default move selectors are used for the
planning entity shift assignment class in local search and move
selectors
are added for the planning entity class
"EmployeeSkillRequirement" and everything is combined in a

    and the construction heuristic is replaced with move selectors  combined in a union to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
<!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode> -->
<solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.NurseRoster
</solutionClass>
<entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
</entityClass>
<entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
</entityClass>
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl
    </scoreDrl>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<termination>
    <!-- Official benchmark secondsSpentLimit allowed on: - ge0ffrey's main 
        pc: sprint 11, medium 700, long 42000 -->
    <secondsSpentLimit>700</secondsSpentLimit>
    <!--<bestScoreLimit>-0hard/-999999soft</bestScoreLimit> -->
</termination>
<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </downcastEntityClass>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </downcastEntityClass>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </swapMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </swapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>
<localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>

        <!-- Move Selectors for ShiftAssignment this was the default configuration 
            from the example -->
        <moveListFactory>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.solver.move.factory.EmployeeChangeMoveFactory
            </moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <moveListFactory>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.solver.move.factory.ShiftAssignmentSwapMoveFactory
            </moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <moveListFactory>
            <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
            <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.solver.move.factory.ShiftAssignmentPillarPartSwapMoveFactory
            </moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>


        <!-- The move selectors for the second plannig entity class EmployeeSkillRequirement -->
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                </entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>employee</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
        <swapMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                </entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>employee</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </swapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
        <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>800</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
</localSearch>
```

**Config 2:**

Second i looked at the documentation and found this hint that says that it is easier to deal with multiple planning entity classes if there are two different construction heuristic parts for each of them
http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#allocateEntityFromQueueMultipleEntityClasses
so i tried this configuration too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
<!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode> -->
<solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.NurseRoster
</solutionClass>
<entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
</entityClass>
<entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
</entityClass>
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl
    </scoreDrl>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<termination>
    <!-- Official benchmark secondsSpentLimit allowed on: - ge0ffrey's main 
        pc: sprint 11, medium 700, long 42000 -->
    <secondsSpentLimit>700</secondsSpentLimit>
    <!--<bestScoreLimit>-0hard/-999999soft</bestScoreLimit> -->
</termination>
<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </downcastEntityClass>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                    </downcastEntityClass>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </swapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>
<constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                    </downcastEntityClass>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                    </entityClass>
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                    </downcastEntityClass>
                    <variableName>employee</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
            </swapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
</constructionHeuristic>
<localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>

        <!-- Move Selectors for ShiftAssignment this was the default configuration 
            from the example -->
        <moveListFactory>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.solver.move.factory.EmployeeChangeMoveFactory
            </moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <moveListFactory>
            <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
            <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.solver.move.factory.ShiftAssignmentSwapMoveFactory
            </moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <moveListFactory>
            <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
            <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.solver.move.factory.ShiftAssignmentPillarPartSwapMoveFactory
            </moveListFactoryClass>
        </moveListFactory>
        <!-- besides this default configuration from optaplaner i also tried this here

        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.
                </entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                </downcastEntityClass>
                <variableName>employee</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
        <swapMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                </entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.ShiftAssignment
                </downcastEntityClass>
                <variableName>employee</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </swapMoveSelector>-->


        <!-- The move selectors for the second plannig entity class EmployeeSkillRequirement -->
        <changeMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                </entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                </downcastEntityClass>
                <variableName>employee</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </changeMoveSelector>
        <swapMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector>
                <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                </entityClass>
            </entitySelector>
            <valueSelector>
                <downcastEntityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.EmployeeSkillRequirement
                </downcastEntityClass>
                <variableName>employee</variableName>
            </valueSelector>
        </swapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
        <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>800</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
</localSearch>
```

I also tried some other configurations that are similar to these ones, still, no luck.

How can i fix this and make it working?

Edit:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalling of solverConfigResource (org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringSolverConfig.xml) fails.
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.XStreamXmlSolverFactory.configure(XStreamXmlSolverFactory.java:114)
at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:66)
at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.createSolver(NurseRosteringApp.java:50)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:90)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:77)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:73)
at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.main(NurseRosteringApp.java:38)
Caused by: " com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field   org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMoveSelectorConfig.valueSelector
---- Debugging information ----
field               : valueSelector
class               :      org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMoveSelect    orConfig
required-type       :     org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMoveSelect    orConfig
converter-type      :    com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 98
class[1]            :       org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.move.composite.UnionMoveSel    ectorConfig
class[2]            :    org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig
class[3]            : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.XStreamXmlSolverFactory.configure(XStreamXmlSolverFactory.java:114)
at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:66)
at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.createSolver(NurseRosteringApp.java:50)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:90)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:77)
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:73)
at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.main(NurseRosteringApp.java:38)
```

Comment: What's the caused by of that illegalargument exception? The XStream exception message should clearly indicate what didn't parse. I suspect it can be different for both configs you've written here. We intend to provide an XSD schema sooner or later.

Comment: About config 1: A `swapMoveSelector` nested in a `constructionHeuristic` doesn't make sense. See [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#allocateEntityFromQueueMultipleEntityClasses) of the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common mistake is to add whitespace in classname properties that doesn't get parsed correctly. This fails during parsing:

```
<solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.NurseRoster
</solutionClass>
```

but this succeeds in getting parsed:

```
<solutionClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.domain.NurseRoster</solutionClass>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.Thanks.I also removed the swapMoveSelector from the construction heuristic as you suggested.

Now i get another error, i posted it as an edit.

Comment: It's best to create a new question for new questions, otherwise it get too long to read (and also to long for other users with the same problem to identify it as such). That being said, it's another Xstream unmarshalling error. If you check the error message, it basically says you got a `<valueSelector>` element in a `<swapMoveSelector>` element, but if you look at the `SwapMoveSelectorConfig`, you'll notice there is no such field there.

Comment: Oh yea: **to find the java class for an XML element, just add the suffix `Config` to its name**.

Comment: Again it worked like a charm, everything works! I posted another question regarding your proposal, and answered it there to help the community. Here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090831/optaplanner-unmarshalling-of-solverconfigresource-fails/36090832#36090832. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe you should consider trim the value and remove al new lines or tabs